# In Gang setzen oder in Gang bringen?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, word-choice

Kann jemand bitte den Unterschied zwischen „etwas is Gang bringen“ und „etwas in Gang setzen“ erklären?

- Es war schwer, den Motor in Gang zu bringen.
- Es war schwer, den Motor in Gang zu setzen.

Vielen Dank

Comment: Es gibt so gut wie keinen Unterschied.

Comment: Ein geringfüger  Unterschied betrifft *Kollokationen*. Man *bringt* typischerweise Maschinen oder Geräte in Gang, während z.B. Vorgänge oder Verfahren im übertragenen Sinne in Gang *gesetzt* werden.

Comment: Wer sagt, dass es einen Unterschied gibt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich sehe keinen grundlegenden Unterschied, würde '*(wieder) in Gang bringen*' jedoch eher auf festgefahrene Verhandlungen, stockende Gespräche, ein Gerät, das nicht mehr läuft, auf länger dauernde Prozesse oder chemische Reaktionen anwenden.

'*In Gang setzen*' heißt für mich einerseits schlichtes '*einschalten*'. '*Sich in Gang setzen*' ist gleichbedeutend mit '*sich in Bewegung setzen*' = *anfangen, sich zu bewegen*, und auch mit '*anspringen, zu laufen anfangen* (Motor)'.

Wenn man sagen will, dass ein Projekt wie z.B. eine Bürgerinitiative 'zum Laufen gebracht' (angeleiert) wurde, kann man vermutlich beides benutzen, da beide Ausdrücke sich figurativ einsetzen lassen. Beispiele: 1. "Er hat mit seiner Anzeige etwas in Gang gesetzt, über das sich das ganze Dorf entzweien sollte." (= den Stein ins Rollen gebracht, eine Lawine losgetreten).  2. "Es war in dieser verfahrenen Situation schwierig, die Leute wieder an einen Tisch und so etwas wie Gespräche in Gang zu bringen. Die haben sich am Anfang einfach nur angeschwiegen."

Bezogen auf einen **Motor** verstehe ich '*in Gang **setzen***' als '***starten***' und '*in Gang **bringen***' als 'nach einem Aussetzer oder nach sehr langer Standzeit ***wieder zum Laufen bringen***', weil 'bringen' für mich assoziiert, dass ein Widerstand zu überwinden ist, vgl. 'jemanden entgegen seinen ursprünglichen Absichten dazu bringen, etwas zu tun' oder 'etwas fertigbringen' im Sinne von '*es über sich bringen, sich dazu überwinden*'.

Von manchen wird diese Sichtweise jedoch nicht geteilt, und es gibt viele Fundstellen, die für einen unterschiedslosen Gebrauch beider Wendungen sprechen. Das Problem dabei ist, dass man auch einen Motor, der "nicht will", '*in Gang setzen*' kann, was dann soviel heißt wie '*an den Punkt kommen, dass er läuft*.' Die dabei zu überwindenden Probleme kann man beim Erzählen ausblenden, oder man wählt eine andere Konstruktion, welche andeutet, dass es beim Anlassen des Motors nicht mit dem Drücken des Startknopfs getan war: '*es hinbekommen / schaffen / fertigbringen, den Motor in Gang zu setzen.*' Pragmatisch gesehen ist das Resultat dasselbe: Am Ende läuft der Motor. Für manche mag eine genauere Unterscheidung bei der Wahl zwischen *setzen* und *bringen* daher zu haarspalterisch sein.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103261/discussion-on-answer-by-ralf-joerres-in-gang-setzen-oder-in-gang-bringen).